# Selecting default value in DropDownListFor html helper not working - ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I created a controller which accepts one parameter from query string, this parameter is an integer, and i have a drop down list , i want to set a default value from the list based on the parameter value , but it's not working. I am using `DropDownListFor` html helper to create the list.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int accountType)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Competitor",Value = "Competitor"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Consultant",Value = "Consultant"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Customer",Value = "Customer"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Investor",Value = "Investor"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Partner",Value = "Partner"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Influencer",Value = "Influencer"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Press",Value = "Press"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Prospect",Value = "Prospect"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Reseller",Value = "Reseller"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Supplier",Value = "Supplier"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Vendor",Value = "Vendor"},
                new SelectListItem{Text = "Other",Value = "Other"}
            };

            Account account = new Account
            {
                Name = "khaled",
                Email = "test",
                AccountType = listItems[accountType].Text
            };
            ViewBag.items = listItems;
            return View(account);
        }
```

My View:
@using System.Globalization
@model Form_Task.Models.Account

```
<div class="form-group">
       @Html.Label("accounttype", "Account Type")
       @Html.DropDownListFor(Model=>Model.AccountType,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.items,new{@class = "form-control", @disabled="disabled"})
</div>
```

My Model:

```
public class Account
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string AccountType { get; set;}
    }
```

If i change `accountType` to string and create the model like the following, it works fine:

```
Account account = new Account
                {
                    Name = "khaled",
                    Email = "test",
                    AccountType = accountType
                };
```

Comment: SelectListItem has a boolean property called `Selected`, just set it to true when defining your SelectListItem's

Comment: @SeanT, i want to set it dynamically

Comment: From the int? So that int corresponds to the position in your `List<SelectListItem>` you want to be set as selected?

Comment: yes that what i am attempting to do

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it sounds like you want to set the selected value based on its position in the list... If you must to that then this code before you pass it to the viewbag will work.

```
        Account account = new Account
        {
            Name = "khaled",
            Email = "test",
            AccountType = listItems[accountType].Text
        };

        listItems[accountType].Selected = true;//Add this line
        ViewBag.items = listItems;
        return View(account);
```

However this is not a good way to do things, what happens if the order changes? What happens if the `int` you get from the query string is larger than the length of `listItems`?

The more typical method is to set `selected` based on the value of your `SelectListItem`, something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string accountType)//pass through the listitems value instead of its position in the list.
{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Competitor",Value = "Competitor"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Consultant",Value = "Consultant"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Customer",Value = "Customer"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Investor",Value = "Investor"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Partner",Value = "Partner"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Influencer",Value = "Influencer"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Press",Value = "Press"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Prospect",Value = "Prospect"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Reseller",Value = "Reseller"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Supplier",Value = "Supplier"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Vendor",Value = "Vendor"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Other",Value = "Other"}
        };

        //loop through and check for a match
        foreach (var item in listItems)
        {
            item.Selected = item.Value == accountType;
        }

        Account account = new Account
        {
            Name = "khaled",
            Email = "test",
            AccountType = listItems[accountType].Text
        };
        ViewBag.items = listItems;
        return View(account);
}
```

This way, if the value doesn't match your query string it won't cause an exception and your method will still complete.

Edit - Just noticed you're using `@Html.DropDownListFor()`, change this to `@Html.DropDownList()` or just html5 control as otherwise `Selected` attribute is ignored.

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.Label("accounttype", "Account Type")
   <select name="AccountType" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
       @foreach(var item in (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.items)
       {
       <option value='@item.Value' @(item.Selected ? "selected" : "")>@item.Text</option> 
       }
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Just noticed you used @DropDownListFor(), have amended

Comment: it's not working , this issue wasted my whole day , i'm so depressed lol

Comment: I tend to just go with html5 select anyway - see my edit

Comment: unfortunately, there is no errors at all. First item of the list is displayed, that's it. I have to use razor, it's a requirement

Comment: You have disabled attribute. So you won't be able to use the select. Remove it

Comment: Well having disabled will prevent you from using the select so remove that. I'm guessing nothing happened because it was cached. Remove it and retry in a private browsing session